# Comparing to Object in C#

Tags: c#, object, compare

Hello I am new in C# and i have a little question : 
when I call the method `list1.contains(product)` is it like java we need to override the Equals method ?

if yes ? is this the way to do it ?

```
public partial class product 
{
    public product()
    {
    }

    public int idProduct { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (this == obj)
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (this.GetType() != obj.GetType())
        {
            return false;
        }

        product other = (product)obj;
        if (idProduct != other.idProduct)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should override Equals to provide equality semantics for your class.
By default, reference equality will be in play.

Your Equals method will work, but in C# we can also override the == operator. Therefore, it might not be safe to use in an Equals method. It would be better to use `ReferenceEquals` for the reference comparisons:

```
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(obj,null))
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (ReferenceEquals(this,obj))
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (this.GetType() != obj.GetType())
        {
            return false;
        }
        product other = (product)obj;
        if (idProduct != other.idProduct)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: +1. It may be worth to mention that most Linq/collection methods take comparers as argument - so it is not strictly necessary to implement custom `Equal`.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov What you mean?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan [Enumerable.Contains(..., IEqualityComparer<TSource>)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb339118%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [@driis answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26918241/961113), you can also create a new [`IEqualityComparer<Product>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151(v=vs.110).aspx) like:

```
public sealed class ProductEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Product>
{
    public bool Equals(Product x, Product y)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, null)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(y, null)) return false;
        if (x.GetType() != y.GetType()) return false;
        return x.idProduct == y.idProduct;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Product obj)
    {
        return obj.idProduct;
    }
}
```

And then you can pass that `Comparer` to `Contains` like:

```
if (list1.Contains(product, new ProductEqualityComparer()))
{

}
```

Where `list1` is `List<Product>` defined as:

```
Product product = new Product { idProduct = 1 };
List<Product> list1 = new List<Product>
{
    new Product{idProduct =  1},
    new Product{idProduct = 2}
};
```

Or you can inherit from `EqualityComparer<T>` and then override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`, because [MSDN states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151(v=vs.110).aspx)

> We recommend that you derive from the `EqualityComparer<T>` class
>   instead of implementing the `IEqualityComparer<T>` interface, because
>   the `EqualityComparer<T>` class tests for equality using the
>   `IEquatable<T>.Equals` method instead of the Object.Equals method.
>   This is consistent with the Contains, IndexOf, LastIndexOf, and Remove
>   methods of the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` class and other generic
>   collections.

```
public sealed class ProductEqualityComparer : EqualityComparer<Product>
{
    public override bool Equals(Product x, Product y)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, null)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(y, null)) return false;
        if (x.GetType() != y.GetType()) return false;
        return x.idProduct == y.idProduct;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode(Product obj)
    {
        return obj.idProduct;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably worth mentioning that you can shorten your code a bit by implementing `IEquatable<T>`.

[`List<T>.Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339171(v=vs.110).aspx) will call `IEquatable<T>.Equals` if the type in your generic list implements `IEquatable`, avoiding the cast:

```
public class product : IEquatable<product>
{
    public int idProduct { get; set; }

    // List<product>.Contains will call IEquatable<product>.Equals if available.
    public bool Equals(product other)
    {
        return ReferenceEquals(other, this) || other.idProduct == this.idProduct;
    }

    // Note: you should still override object.Equals.
    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        return this.Equals(other as product);
    }
}
```

Also in C# classes are typically `PascalCased` and not `camelCased`.